# mock test if/else with Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, sonarqube, karma-jasmine

I have this snippet of code:

```js
exportData(type: 'config' | 'equipment'): Observable<any> {
    url = '';
    if (type === 'config') url = `${path}Exportconfig`;
    else if (type === 'equipment') url = `${path}ExportEquipment`;
    
    return httpClient(...);

}
```

I mocked the tests but still having this message in sonar **branches should have sufficient coverage by tests**

Here are my tests

```js
it('export configuration', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'exportData');

    const type = 'config';
    service.exportData(type)
    expect(service.exportData).toHaveBeenCalledWith('config');
})
```

The same thing has been done for the other value of type. I think I'm missing something on the coverage for the conditions. Any thoughts?

Comment: That test doesn't call anything. Even if it did call `service.exportData`, it would be calling the _spy_. And given only one test for `'config'`, you're clearly not going to cover the `'equipment'` path. It's not entirely clear why you thought that would be adequately covered.

Comment: sorry @jonrsharpe I just edited the test snippet where I call the function **exportData** before **expect**

Comment: But you're still spying on the thing you're supposed to be testing. Of course it got called, _you just called it_ - the test is pointless, it only asserts on the behaviour _of the test_.

Comment: could you clarify more here @jonrsharpe. Are you actually saying since Im 'only' spying on the method and not calling it the test is not actually running and testing all the branches?

Comment: I can't remember if Jasmine spies call through by default or not, but even so **spying is pointless here**. And at most one branch is covered because you're only calling with one input, you'd need at least two tests for that logic.

Comment: Exactly see the last sentence of my question: **The same thing has been done for the other value of type**. So I have 2 tests both the same logic, each with a different value of **type**.

Comment: And which line(s) aren't covered? Is there any conditional logic piped onto the HttpClient request? Given you're spying on the method, is _any_ of it executed?

Comment: No condition on the httpClient. A simple GET call. Sonarqube is highlighting the if/else of the function as not covered by tests.

Comment: And if you get rid of the pointless spying, any difference? It would simplify the example, if nothing else.

Comment: without them the test fails with "Expected a Spy, but got Function" error

Comment: You also have to remove the pointless assertion... Again, of course it got called, **your test just called it**.

Comment: I was able to figure out why it broke in sonar @jonrsharpe. So apparently I have to add a final else to my test in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your test case like this:

```
it('export configuration', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'exportData');
     
    // This will serve the 'if' condition
    const type = 'config';
    service.exportData(type)
    expect(service.exportData).toHaveBeenCalledWith('config');


    // This will serve the 'else-if' condition
    const type2 = 'equipment';
    service.exportData(type2)
    expect(service.exportData).toHaveBeenCalledWith('equipment');

    // This will serve the 'else' condition
    const type3 = 'not-equipment-not-config';
    service.exportData(type3)
    expect(service.exportData).toHaveBeenCalledWith('not-equipment-not-config');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently adding a final case with a closing **else* with cover all branches.
Final function should look like this:

```js
exportData(type: 'config' | 'equipment'): Observable<any> {
    url = '';
    if (type === 'config') url = `${path}Exportconfig`;
    else if (type === 'equipment') url = `${path}ExportEquipment`;
    else return null;
    
    return httpClient(...);

}
```